# Python command buttons to change the position the widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have coded this simple GUI program, which changes the color of the text with the help of the radio buttons. When they are being clicked, the color of the text changes. I also want to add new simple default buttons, which will move the text left and right when they are being clicked. I wonder if you could help me about how they are being coded for that specific command. This is how my code looks like so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("WOOSAL")

def changeColourF(colour):
    root.configure()
    choice1.configure()
    choice2.configure()
    choice3.configure()
    choice4.configure()
    w.configure(fg=colour)

v =StringVar()
v.set("L")

choice1 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Red", value =1, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("red"))
choice1.grid(row =0, column =0)

choice2 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Yellow", value =2, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("yellow"))
choice2.grid(row =0, column =1)

choice3 =Radiobutton(root, text ="White", value =3, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("white"))
choice3.grid(row =0, column =2)

choice4 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Gray", value =4, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("gray"))
choice4.grid(row =0, column =3)

choice5 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Green", value =5, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("green"))
choice5.grid(row =0, column =4)

w = Label(root, text="Welcome", height=6, width=10)
w.grid(row=1, column=0)


buttonLeft = Button(root,text ="<=",height=1, width=1)
buttonLeft.grid(row=2,column=1)


buttonRight = Button(root,text ="=>",height=1, width=1)
buttonRight.grid(row=2,column=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the column to move the text.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("WOOSAL")

def changeColourF(colour):
    root.configure()
    choice1.configure()
    choice2.configure()
    choice3.configure()
    choice4.configure()
    w.configure(fg=colour)

v =StringVar()
v.set("L")

choice1 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Red", value =1, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("red"))
choice1.grid(row =0, column =0)

choice2 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Yellow", value =2, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("yellow"))
choice2.grid(row =0, column =1)

choice3 =Radiobutton(root, text ="White", value =3, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("white"))
choice3.grid(row =0, column =2)

choice4 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Gray", value =4, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("gray"))
choice4.grid(row =0, column =3)

choice5 =Radiobutton(root, text ="Green", value =5, variable =v, command =lambda: changeColourF("green"))
choice5.grid(row =0, column =4)

w = Label(root, text="Welcome", height=6, width=10)
w.grid(row=1, column=0)



def move_right():
    w.grid(column=w.grid_info()['column'] + 1)


def move_left():
    w.grid(column=w.grid_info()['column'] - 1)



buttonLeft = Button(root,text ="<=",height=1, width=1, command=move_left)
buttonLeft.grid(row=2,column=1)


buttonRight = Button(root,text ="=>",height=1, width=1, command=move_right)
buttonRight.grid(row=2,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```